# mvc 4 and jquery 1.9.1 where to find the other updated javascript files?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an app in MVC4, and I need to use Jquery version 1.9.1

By default the MVC 4 application comes with

```
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

When you go to the jquery.validate plugin home page it only supports 1.9.0
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

are there updates to these that support jquery 1.9.1?

Thanks

I am using the migrate plugin so that it doesn't error out

Comment: you can use the latest version of `jQuery` with these plugins. Try to get the lastes Package from [NuGet](http://Nuget/org) AND you can use the `NuGet Package Manager` from your Visual Studio IDE

Comment: Ravi - are you saying the latest version of jquery 1.11.0 fixes these issue?

Comment: Yes! you can get all updated apis from `NuGet` it will resolve all dependencies as well. Like `jQuery.Validate.js` depends on `Jquery` NuGet will automatically resolve dependencies issues

Comment: Why do you suppose it doesn't work with 1.9.1? The home page says that it's been tested with 1.9.0, which doesn't mean it doesn't work with 1.9.1. have you ried it?

Comment: Ravi - does not work, nu get does not have a version compatible

Comment: JotaBe - Well for starters I know it doesnt work because like you read it was tested upto 1.9.0 and because I actually tried it with 1.9.1